# Issues in locating elements and re sizing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, cardlayout

Please have a look at the following code

**WizardPanel**

```
package wizardGUI;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WizardPanel extends JDialog
{
    private JPanel cardPanel, buttonPanel;
    private JButton next,previous;
    private CardLayout c1;

    private FileSelector fileSelector;
    private DelemeterSelector delemeterSelector;

    private int count = 1;

    public WizardPanel()
    {
        //Intializing instance variables
        fileSelector = FileSelector.getInstance();
        delemeterSelector = DelemeterSelector.getInstance();

        cardPanel = new JPanel();
        c1 = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel.setLayout(c1);

        cardPanel.add(fileSelector,"1");
        cardPanel.add(delemeterSelector,"2");

        c1.show(cardPanel, "1");;


        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        next = new JButton("Next");
        next.addActionListener(new NextButtonAction());
        previous = new JButton("Previous");

        buttonPanel.add(next);
        buttonPanel.add(previous);

        //Creating the GUI
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(cardPanel,"Center");
        this.add(buttonPanel,"South");

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    private class NextButtonAction implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {

                c1.show(cardPanel, "2");

        }
    }
}
```

**FileSelector**

```
package wizardGUI;

/*This is the first panel is wazard GUI. Using this window user can select the correct file
  which contains the data required to create the table
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileSelector extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel fileName, description;
    private JTextField fileTxt;
    private JButton browse;

    private GridBagLayout gbl;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    private static FileSelector instance = null;

    private FileSelector()
    {
        //Intializing instance variables
        fileName = new JLabel("File Name: ");
        description = new JLabel("Specify the source of the data");

        fileTxt = new JTextField(10);

        browse = new JButton("Browse");

        gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        //Creating GUI
        this.setLayout(gbl);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(description,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,10,0,0);
        this.add(locationPanel(),gbc);

        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    }

    private JPanel locationPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel.add(fileName);
        panel.add(fileTxt);
        panel.add(browse);

        return panel;
    }

    public static FileSelector getInstance()
    {
        if(instance==null)
        {
            instance = new FileSelector();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

**DelemeterSelector**

```
/*This is the second windows in wizard
This class is designed to let the user to select the delemeter to break information */

package wizardGUI;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DelemeterSelector extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel description;
    private JRadioButton tabBtn, semicolanBtn, commaBtn, spaceBtn;
    private JTextArea txtArea;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private ButtonGroup btnGroup;

    private GridBagLayout gbl;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    private static DelemeterSelector instance = null;

    private DelemeterSelector()
    {
        //Initializing instance variables
        description = new JLabel("What delemeter separates your fields? Select the appropreiate delemeter");

        tabBtn = new JRadioButton("Tab");
        semicolanBtn = new JRadioButton("Semicolan");
        commaBtn = new JRadioButton("Comma");
        spaceBtn = new JRadioButton("Space");

        btnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        btnGroup.add(tabBtn);
        btnGroup.add(semicolanBtn);
        btnGroup.add(commaBtn);
        btnGroup.add(spaceBtn);

        txtArea = new JTextArea(20,70);

        scroll = new JScrollPane(txtArea);

        gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        this.setLayout(gbl);

        //Creating the GUI
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(20,0,0,0);
        this.add(description,gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(20,0,0,0);
        this.add(radioPanel(),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        this.add(scroll,gbc);
    }

    private JPanel radioPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel.add(tabBtn);
        panel.add(semicolanBtn);
        panel.add(commaBtn);
        panel.add(spaceBtn);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choose the Delimeter that seperates your fields"));

        return panel;
    }

    public static DelemeterSelector getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new DelemeterSelector();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the "FileSelector" looks really ugly. I want everything to be appear at the top of the pane, but instead, everything appears in middle!! I have even tried `GridBagLayout` options to make it resizable, it also failed. The look of it is in the attached image

[image]

How can I make it look nice and scalable? Please help

Comment: You only have to look at "FileSelector" anyway

Comment: Then only post the relevant code instead of adding a small comment saying: "hey, 90% of the code I dumped is unneeded. Please filter it when you, a volunteer, try to solve my problem". [A little reading on posting a question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: It becomes like this because the "DelemeterSelector" is using more space than "FileSelector". So both classes are needed. Both classes only contains GUI elements. Removing one elements will mess everything

Comment: No, both classes are not needed. Either you can have this behavior by just manually resizing the JFrame (if the resize behavior is incorrect). Otherwise a CardLayout with a dummy panel containing a really big component would have been sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick example which shows the same behavior and a fix, without the need for all that external code (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CardLayoutDemo {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );

        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel( cardLayout );

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(  );
        firstPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout(  ) );
        firstPanel.add( new JLabel( "Contents" ) );

        //wrap the smallest panel instead of directly adding it
        contentPane.add( firstPanel, "first" );
//        JPanel wrappedPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(  ) );
//        wrappedPanel.add( firstPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
//        contentPane.add( wrappedPanel, "first" );

        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(  ) );
        secondPanel.add( new JComponent() {
          @Override
          public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension( 500, 500 );
          }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        contentPane.add( secondPanel, "second" );

        cardLayout.show( contentPane, "first" );

        frame.setContentPane( contentPane );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

When you run the code without making changes, it will show you a panel where the contents is centered (the `firstPanel`). Without making any changes to the `firstPanel`, but simply by wrapping it you can keep it at the top. Just replace the `contentPane.add( firstPanel, "first" )` by the 3 lines (in comment) underneath.

There are a lot of times where [nesting layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/1076463) makes it easier to get the desired result, and imo this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The `fill` constraints are not necessary in this case. Also, `gridx` and `gridy` start from 0. This sample code

```
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    this.add(description,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0,10,0,0);
    this.add(locationPanel(),gbc);
```

produces this

[image]

Not sure if this is what you want though.

Comment: hmm..This seems to be what I am seeking for...Anyway I will try it later because it is nearly 1.00 AM now :) Thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: but what about the size of elements? As you can see, they are very small, not even matching to the width of the window.. When resizing, it becomes worst! How to solve this as well?